# Apply warp effect to object from script

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, illustrator-effects

How do I apply a warp effect to an object from an Illustrator script (JavaScript)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways to go about this:

1. Already have an existing graphic style that you can apply to an item. (https://forums.adobe.com/message/4380742#4380742#4380742)
   The example from Muppet Mark reads:

   var doc = app.activeDocument;
   var fuzz = doc.graphicStyles.getByName( 'fuzz' );
   fuzz.applyTo( doc.pageItems[0] );
2. The more complicated method is to use the live-effect XML string, a special command syntax for Illustrator scripting that has only been revealed to us in the last couple of years. For complex graphic styles or effects it still may take a lot of work to even determine what the correct string *is* because this feature is completely undocumented. For your warp needs, this should suffice though.
   See this link here (https://forums.adobe.com/message/9356527#9356527)

`#target illustrator
    function test(){
      var doc = app.activeDocument; 
      var p = doc.selection[0]; 
      var effectStr_2 = '<LiveEffect name="Adobe Deform"><Dict data="R DeformValue 0.45 R DeformVert 0 B Rotate 0 I DeformStyle 1 R DeformHoriz 0 "/></LiveEffect>';
      p.applyEffect(effectStr_2);
    };
    test();`

Comment: I got the LiveEffect approach to work. Thanks.

Comment: That's just incredible!

Comment: I see what you did there!